# SQL request for several tables and operations in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the following 3 tables: unit, stage, stats.

```
      unit                      stage
+----+--------+   +----+-------+---------------------+
| id | status |   | id |unit_id|        date         |
+----+--------+   +----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |      2 |   |  1 |     2 | 2013-11-22 00:00:00 |
|  2 |      3 |   |  2 |     2 | 2013-11-26 12:00:00 |
|  3 |      3 |   |  3 |     3 | 2013-10-11 00:00:00 |
|  4 |      0 |   |  4 |     1 | 2013-12-29 00:00:00 |
+----+--------+   +----+-------+---------------------+

                     stats
+----+----------+---------------------+-------+
| id | stage_id |        date         | clicks|
+----+----------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | 2013-11-22 00:00:00 |    10 |
|  2 |        1 | 2013-11-23 00:00:00 |    20 |
|  3 |        1 | 2013-11-24 00:00:00 |    25 |
|  4 |        2 | 2013-11-26 00:00:00 |    15 |
|  5 |        2 | 2013-11-27 12:00:00 |    21 |
|  6 |        3 | 2013-12-29 00:00:00 |     8 |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------+
```

I need a request, that will produce the following response:

```
+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| unit.id |   stage.min.date    | sum(stats.max.clicks) |
+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|       2 | 2013-11-22 00:00:00 |                    46 |
|       3 | 2013-12-29 00:00:00 |                     8 |
+---------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

by the following rules:

1) `unit.id` - show only units with `unit.status=3`

2) `stage.min.date` - minimal `stage.date` for corresponding `unit_id`

3) `sum(stats.max.clicks)` - sum of `stats.clicks` with max dvalues for each `stage_id` associated with corresponding `unit_id`. In my example 46 = 25(`stage_id=1`) + 21(`stage_id=2`)

The problem is in min.date and sum of clicks - I have no idea how to get it in one query. Definitely it`s not a problem to do it using php code and several requests.

[Schema in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa241)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want us to write your code, right?

Comment: if you tried any query or code please post that. it will help to solve issue

Comment: The problem is I cannot compile this in one query without involving php coding.

Comment: response-example is crap e.g. stats_id 6: 8 clicks/stage_id 3, stage_id 3 points to unit_id 1 (status 2)...

Comment: you can at least try in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: "dvalues" are "dates", right?

Comment: stage_id 3 has 8 clicks. stage_id 3 corresponds to unit_id 1. unit_id 1 has a status of 2. Therefore, stage_id 3 should be excluded from the result. Therefore, 8 clicks cannot appear in the result!! Likewise, there is no stat for stage_id 4. Therefore unit_id 3 also cannot appear in the result. See fiddle. For my own sanity, I amended some column names http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5732e1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ask myself, why I do this? Your example resonse has an error, and does not match your fiddle... but:

```
SELECT
  cc.unit_id, MIN(cc.date) as stage_min_date , SUM(dd.clicks) as stats_max_clicks
FROM
  stage cc
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    bb.stage_id, bb.clicks
  FROM
    stats bb LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT id, stage_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
      FROM stats
      GROUP BY stage_id
    ) aa
  ON
    aa.max_date = bb.date
  WHERE
    aa.max_date IS NOT NULL
) dd
ON cc.id = dd.stage_id
LEFT JOIN unit ee 
ON ee.id = cc.unit_id
WHERE ee.status = 3
GROUP BY cc.unit_id
```

...

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not solves my problem. Here`s a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6457/2/0)

Comment: I changed some things.
Please double- or tripple-check your eamples and fiddles, it's not helpful with all those errors.